# How can I combining like-rows in CSV to fill missing data?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that might look like:

```
id, value01, value02,
01, , 01b,
01, 01a, ,
02, , 02b,
02, 02a, 02b,
...
```

As you can see, I have duplicate rows where one of the duplicates (can be more than two) (determined as a duplicate by the id) has missing values, and the other duplicates contain other values missing.

I think someone who managed this CSV output wrote twice to the CSV rather than combine results and output once, so now I need to find a clean way to do this.

So far, my work is:

```py
import csv

def combine_dups():
    data = []
    with open("file.csv", newline='', mode='r') as csvFile:
        csvData = csv.DictReader(csvFile)

        for row in csvData:
            for lookahead in csvData:
                # Check if lookahead and current row have matching ids
                if row["id"] == lookahead["id"]:
                    # Loop through columns of row and lookahead
                    for col in row:
                        # If current row's column is blank, take value from lookahead
                        if row[col] == '' or row[col] is None:
                            row[col] = lookahead[col]
            data.append(row) # Add new filled out, completed row

            # Manage data to no longer contain excess duplicates
            # Code here??
    return data
```

This code isn't correct, as it as:

1. If loops through csvData for each row, rather than looping through all data after current row. This is easily solved using a for loop using an index, but I left that out for simplicity.
2. The row is filled in with the missing data, but this operation is done multiple times for the other values with identical id's. How can I avoid this?

Edit:
For clarity, the NEW csv should look like:

```
id, value01, value02,
01, 01a, 01b,
02, 02a, 02b,
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

data = {}
with open(filename) as csvInFile:
        csvData = csv.DictReader(csvInFile)
        fieldnames = csvData.fieldnames
        for row in csvData:
            # Combine data and update. 
            data.setdefault(row['id'], dict()).update({k:v for k,v in row.items() if v.strip() and not data.get(row['id']).get(k)})

with open(filename, "w",  newline='') as csvOutFile:
    csvOutData = csv.DictWriter(csvOutFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csvOutData.writeheader()
    csvOutData.writerows(data.values())  # Write data.
```

**Output:**

```
id, value01, value02
01, 01a, 01b
02, 02a, 02b
```

Comment: This looks very promising @Rakesh. I implemented this, however, I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`. Any idea why? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Use `if v ` instead of `if v.strip()`

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I needed `if k is not None` aswell. Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 0):

The could be solved by using a dictionary object to store the values. This csv would be traversed just once for each row.

You can refer to the code below:

```
import csv

c_dict = {}
with open("file.csv", newline='', mode='r') as csvFile:
    csvData = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in csvData:
        if row['id'] not in c_dict.keys():
            c_dict[row['id']] = {}
        if (row['value01'] == '' or row['value01'] is None) or 'value01' in c_dict[row['id']].keys():
            pass
        else:
            c_dict[row['id']]['value01'] = row['value01']
        if (row['value02'] == '' or row['value02'] is None) or 'value02' in c_dict[row['id']].keys():
            pass
        else:
            c_dict[row['id']]['value02'] = row['value02']

keys = ['id', 'value01', 'value02']
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    dict_writer.writerow(keys)
    for k, v in c_dict.items():
        dict_writer.writerow([k, v['value01'], v['value02']])
```

Note: If you have more than these 2 columns, you may `if-else` clause in a loop